# Can I send email via Mandrill without having site ownership?

Tags: email, mandrill

Can I send email via Mandrill without having site ownership? The challenge is I have verified email but I don't have access to change the site settings like "
DKIM" & "SPF".

I have tried blog https://www.jotform.com/help/236-How-to-use-Mandrill-to-Send-Emails-From-Your-Own-Email-Address. But found now mandrill portal has changed & can't find Email menu or form builder menu with out adding domain.

I am doing a POC & can't add DKIM & SPF for Mandrill into main site right now due to long & tedious process of approval for organization site.

Is there any way I can test Mandrill service to send mail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I got the answer, it's **NO**. If you signed up for a Mandrill account on or after **`December 1st, 2015`**, it's not possible.

Added answer if somebody search for the same question.

From Mandrill Site"

> If you signed up for a Mandrill account on or after December 1st,
>   2015, you must add SPF and DKIM records and verify ownership of your
>   sending domains before you can send email through your account.
>   Mandrill will not send any email from unverified domains or domains
>   without valid SPF and DKIM records, including public domains like
>   gmail.com, yahoo.com, and more.
>
> Custom signing domains are only available to Mandrill accounts created
>   before December 1st, 2015. If you signed up for a new Mandrill account
>   on or after December 1st, 2015, the signing_domain parameter will be
>   ignored.
>
> Mail sent from unverified domains or domains without valid SPF and
>   DKIM records will be rejected with the reject_reason, unsigned.
>
> Learn more about SPF and DKIM, and domain verification

SOURCE: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.JSON.html